# configuración nginx/docker en servidor debian

Tags: docker, nginx, debian

Tengo una app "A" que que tiene 3 imagenes docker (front, back, bbdd) levantadas a través de Nginx en puerto 80 en el servidor debian. Ahora he realizado otra app "B" de la misma forma, 3 imagenes docker y levantadas con nginx. Necesito desplegar la segunda app en el mismo servidor, y que se expongan las dos por el puerto 80, y redireccione a una u otra dependiendo del dominio.
Como debería hacer esto? configurar otro nginx que exponga las dos???
Perdón si no se entiende bien, que soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes configurar **[nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)**

Ejemplo

- Grupo A ---> Frontend está mapeado al servidor debian con puerto
  8081:80 (host:frontend docker)
- Grupo B ---> Frontend esta mapeado  al servidor debian con puerto
  8082:80 (host:frontend docker)

Ahora con nginx reverse proxy

- nginx bajo puerto 80 con Dominio_frontend_A  reverse proxy al puerto
  8081
- nginx bajo puerto 80 con Dominio_frontend_B  reverse proxy al puerto
  8082